# Two digits after dot with JavaScript onkeypress event in textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have a textbox on my page.
I have a JavaScript that the user just write numbers and dots in the textbox.
But unfortunately that's not enough.
The user must be limited if it puts a dot then it just can write digits after.
Are not there validation controls or ajax tool kit, or do I have to do it on the `onkeypress` event?

Comment: What would ajax have to do with it?

Comment: You should validate when the data is sent, not on input. Text can be entered without dispatching a keypress event, e.g. pasted or dropped.

Answer (score 0):

at `onblur/onkeyup` event of that `input:text` just check if the entered value match against `/\.\d{2}$/` regular expression

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regexp;

```
function dotdot(val){
    var rx = /\.\./;
    return rx.test(val);
}
```

This way you can ensure the user doesn't type a dot after another dot.

Answer (score 0):

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("ele_id");
textbox.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){ 
  console.log(textbox.value.match(/^[0-9]*?\.[0-9]{2}$/)); 
}, false);
```

just tested it in firefox/firebug, you could use "onkeyup" in html or jquery's bind() to make event handler work in IE